# Make fields required in Workflow Task

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, tasks

Environment : Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

I have a workflow that ask someone to do a custom task (created myself).
This task has just 3 fields like "Approval", "Assigned To" and "Comments".

I want to **make required** 2 of these fields.
I tried to do that by modify the "Task" Content Type. In there, I can put each status field on "Required (must contain information)" like on this picture below :

[image: Required field]

[From](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-content-types-understand-use-create)

Is this the good way to do that by Content Types ?
If yes, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Ok then, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Make sure your custom content type is actually being used by the List. Go to the task list's List Settings and look under Content Types.

Comment: Yes, I can see it. It is "visible on the new button" but it is not the content type use by default in the task list. But it is here.